# Confused about <!-- ko if: $parent.name == name --> in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've encountered this Knockout code and I'm confused about what the below code is performing:

```
   <!-- ko if: $parent.name == name -->
   <a data-bind='text: name'></a> 
   <!-- /ko -->
```

Shouldn't this code be interpreted as a comment?

Reading the documentation:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html
this looks like a custom binding?

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_4_using_foreach_without_a_container_element

Comment: JavaScript can read HTML comments and do whatever you want it to do with them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a knockout conditional comment. The HTML inside the comment block is only executed if the code validates to true. Knockout can read and process this comment for you. You don't have to do anything special. Simply supply the conditional and make sure the variables you reference do in fact exist. Then sit back and let knockout do the rest.

Comment: It is just amazing.. Knockout can process comments.. :)

Comment: I've spent half a day to get how page that uses this comment feature works. Extremely confusing for knockout newbies.

Answer (score 10):

It's not a custom binding. What you encountered is what [knockout's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) calls a "Virtual Element", it's a binding applied to a piece of code instead of an element. If you want to conditionally evaluate (i.e. bind to your viewmodel) a part of the DOM you can either put it inside a div with an `if` binding or put it inside comments like those.

HTML comments are part of the DOM so there's nothing stopping knockout from retrieving and interpreting them.